# Entity Frameworks gets slow after some queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a code:

```
foreach (var idObject in ids)
{
    var parsedIDs = ParseId(idObject.id);

    var integers = new Dictionary<string, int>() { { "model_id", model }, { "year", 2010 }, { "quarter", 1 }, { "month", 1 }, { "rows", rows }, { "page", page } };
    var strings = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "gr_str", "" }, { "row_id", "" }, { "sidx", sidx }, { "sord", sord } };
    var additionals = new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "rowid", idObject.id },
                                {"contr_group_id_e", parsedIDs[0]},
                                {"nomencl_group_set1_id_e", parsedIDs[1]},
                                {"nomencl_group_set2_id_e", parsedIDs[2]},
                                {"workshop_id_e", parsedIDs[3]},
                                {"unit_meas_id_e", parsedIDs[4]},
                                {"plant_id_e", parsedIDs[5]} };

    foreach (var datePair in queryDates)
    {
        additionals["begin_date_e"] = datePair.Key;
        additionals["end_date_e"] = datePair.Value;

        var parameters = InitParams(integers, strings, additionals).ToArray();

        var lastTimestamp = DateTime.Now;

        var queryResults = ModelEntities.ExecuteStoreQuery<ReadyProductIndexes>(Queries.SaleIndexGetRowByID, "Sale", MergeOption.NoTracking, parameters).ToList();

        Debug.WriteLine("TIme: " + (DateTime.Now - lastTimestamp).TotalSeconds);
    }

    Debug.WriteLine("rowid " + idObject.id);
}
```

There is a problem - on the first `foreach` step everything works fine, but on the second and other query began to work very slow (e. g. 0.2 seconds on the first step and 8 second on the second).

What's wrong in my code?

**EDIT**: I've tryed to use MS SQL profiler, and there is some interesting thing - Profiler shows 8 sec duration of request, but when I tryed to run request from Profiler manually, it runs fast. That is strange.

Comment: Impossible to tell given the lack of code that integrates with this. Where does `queryDates` come from? How is your context setup? These are the sorts of things we need to know. Are you disposing of your context after each request?

Comment: No, I'm not disposing context after each iteration. Have a create context on every iteration?

Comment: I would look up entity framework context management information. Chances are a transaction is still open and its being killed after timing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` at the end of the query

Comment: I'm going to suggest that this is a hack and you should definitely figure out what's actually going wrong. No one else seems to require this. Definitely look into Context management and compare how you're doing it with how others are (perhaps by looking at what @LukeMcGregor has offered you).

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue here is a pretty common one, as your EF context grows stuff takes exponentially longer to query. This is because detect changes (which runs on most EF operations) enumerates every object currently tracked by EF. This means if you are tracking thousands of entities it can take quite a bit of time. Its a bit hard to tell from your code sample where this issue is but it fits the pattern very well. I recommend looking at the .Local collection on your DbSets to confirm there are many items tracked.

I wrote a few articles on this which you can read [here](http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/05/entityframework-performance-and.html) and [here](http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/04/entity-framework-and-asnotracking.html).

The upshot of all of this is that you want to **reduce the amount of stuff EF is tracking** (by using .AsNoTracking or by calling detect changes less) and your queries should be nice and fast.

Comment: And what is the `context` in my case?